# Unity Camera Switching Issue?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

Hi everyone I'm doing a cannonball mode where players will have a UI panel that looks like a snipe screen. This camera will follow the enemy while in regular play there is another camera for normal play mode( this one stays in place). However when I switch between the two wherever the cannon camera moves when I exit with "E" it stays in that moved position. Is there any way where I can manually revert the position of the camera back in place?

```cs
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform target;

    public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
    public Vector3 offset;

    public GameObject scopeOverlay;

    public GameObject Camera;

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("d"))
        {
            Camera.SetActive (false);
            scopeOverlay.SetActive(true);
            Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
            Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
            transform.position = smoothedPosition;

            transform.LookAt (target);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("e"))
        {
            Camera.SetActive (true);
            scopeOverlay.SetActive(false); //To disable it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the initial transform values and restore them like so;

```
private Vector3 initialPosition;
private Quaternion initialRotation;

private void Start ()
{
    // Save initial transform values
    initialPosition = transform.position;
    initialRotation = transform.rotation;
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
    {
        Camera.SetActive(false);
        scopeOverlay.SetActive(true);
        Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
        transform.position = smoothedPosition;

        transform.LookAt(target);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
    {
        // Restore transform values
        transform.position = initialPosition;
        transform.rotation = initialRotation;

        Camera.SetActive(true);
        scopeOverlay.SetActive(false); //To disable it
    }
}
```